# Making easy 12V 100Ah battery charger circuit at home

Tags: transistors, resistors, battery-charging, charger, lead-acid

I need a charger for a 100Ah battery and decided to make one. Now I need to order components and am asking for some help.

I'm following tutorial at [this website](https://makingcircuits.com/blog/12v-100ah-battery-charger-circuit/#comment-7469).

Here is the circuit:

[image]

I'm curious why the power of 0.3Ω resistor (0.3/2W) is rated to 2W when the power there is should be much higher (voltage = 10A * 0.3Ω = 3V --> Power = 3V * 10A = 30 W.)

Should I buy a minimum 30W resistor then?

Also, are 0.7Ω/3W resistor's specifications okay? I'm using an MJ2955 instead of 2N2955 (they should be  the same.)

Comment: I agree that for a charging current of 10 A, this does not "add up". Also, at high input voltages (close to 24 V) at 10 A there's going to be a lot of power dissipation in the 2N2955 transistor. Realize that you don't need to charge a 100 Ah battery at 10 A, you can also use 1 A, it will just take 10x longer. A 1 A charger is easily made using only an LM317 and that has the added benefit that the LM317 **protects itself from overheating**, it will simply reduce the charging current if it gets too hot. I made and use such a single LM317 circuit to charge my 40 Ah car battery.

Comment: Here's an example of the circuit I use: https://www.eleccircuit.com/the-most-lead-acid-battery-charger-circuit-by-lm317/

Comment: Where the supply voltage comes from? Not so sure this charger will handle 10A. The transistor has dissipation absolute max. rating of 110W.

Comment: Thanks for help, now I can see that this circuit is not the best. 1 amp is probably too slow for me because I am making it to charge homemade electric car and I don't want it to charge for 4 days. I will look around the internet for better circuits. Have a nice day.

Comment: What battery chemistry are you charging? They all need different charging…

Comment: You should find another article for reference, the linked one is full of errors and very questionable engineering.  This charger circuit definitely will not charge a battery "with utmost efficiency", if powered by 24V it will dissipate half the input power as heat.  Look for a switching charger, most of the major chip manufacturers make charger chips that can handle lead acid batteries and can be >90% efficient instead of ~50%.

Comment: It's a typo (or worse). Change the 0.3 Ohm resistor to 0.03 Ohm or even 0.01.

Comment: The transistor will dissipate 10 W at 10A for every volt of drop. Heatsink it well. A fan helps heaps.